# How can I import / use StdDraw in java eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, package, draw

I have found 3 questions similar to mine and none of them helped me at all (some of them even had some down votes, the answers I mean).

I wanted do an old homework for learning purposes and it's saying that we can use StdDraw function of java. (What we are supposed to do by the way is drawing the pythagoras-tree!)

But I haven't found a way to import that in java, either it was outdated or it was explained very complicated. : /

Answer (score 2):

"StdDraw" is not part of the Sun/Oracle Java distribution (and never was), which is why you're unable to import it.  I'm guessing that you're referring to a Java class that was developed at Princeton University for educational purposes as part of their stdlib.jar library:

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/

Download that jar to your computer. Assuming that you've already created a project in Eclipse:

1. Right click "Project" and select "Properties"
2. Select "Java Build Path"
3. Select "Libraries" tab
4. Click "Add external JARs..." and select the jar you just downloaded

You should now be able to import StdDraw into your app.

Answer (score 1):

1) Right click on (default package)

2) Build path, configure build path

3) libraries tab

4) Click on Class path

5) Add External JARS.

This worked for me. Other people might say to click on "Add external class folder" if this doesn't work click "add external jars".

Comment: default package is important. it may not work if you click on the folder